# 2 arguments into a one parameter function

Tags: clojure

People,

I started studying clojure a few time ago and i have one question.

In this function:

```
(defn print-coords [coords]
  (let [lat (first coords)
        lon (last coords)]
    (println (str "Latitude: " lat " - " "Longitude: " lon))))
=> #'dev-projects.core/print-coords
```

I'm defining a global function with one parameter.

But, if i invoke these arguments:

```
(print-coords [54 32])
Latitude: 54 - Longitude: 32
=> nil
```

I will get a sucessful answer.

Why does it work? The original function shouldn't only work with one argument?

Comment: You are passing one argument - a vector with two numbers in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you confuse `(print-coords [53 32])` to be `(print-coords 54 32)`.

In the first case, `coords` is the vector `[53 32]` whose `first` is `54` -> `lat` and whose `second` indeed is `lon` `32`. Return value is correctly `nil`, since `println` returns `nil`.

However:

```
user=> (print-coords 54 32)
Execution error (ArityException) at user/eval141 (REPL:1).
Wrong number of args (2) passed to: user/print-coords
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is how `[coords]` in the defn is compatible with `[53 32]` in the call.

A defn's parameters are surrounded by square brackets, but a function call's arguments are not wrapped in any punctuation.  Thus `[53 32]` is literally a vector passed as the 1 argument to the function call.  `[53 32]` corresponds to `coords`.

By the way, print-coords could be defined more idiomatically like this:

```
(defn print-coords [[lat lon]]
  (println (str "Latitude: " lat " - " "Longitude: " lon)))
```

It is still a function of 1 argument.  The only difference is that the 1 argument is immediately *destructured* and names are bound to the first two members.  Now it is pleasantly clear how `[53 32]` corresponds `[lat lon]`.